# macro is ignoring my 'specified file path' and just saving right to documents

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to figure out the syntax here, but the best I can get it to do is save to 'Documents' (with the correct filename specified by range AH5), or I can get it to save to the folder that holds my 'file path folder', but with an incorrect file name.

Any input appreciated.

```
Sub saveWorkbook()
    
    Worksheets("REPORT").Activate
    
        Dim MyPATH As String
        Dim FileNAME As String
            MyPATH = "R:\S_Drive\MY File Path"
            FileNAME = Range("AH5").Value
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileNAME:=FileNAME, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault, CreateBackup:=False
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True   ' Restore Alerts
    Application.Quit
    End Sub
```

Comment: Where is `MyPATH` used?

Comment: Perhaps if you specified that folder in the `SaveAs` method the file would be saved where you expect it to be.

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileNAME:=MyPATH & "\" & FileNAME`

Comment: @Tim Williams 

Thanks, this saved the file to the right location with the correct file name.